# How to minify every request on js file with mod_pagespeed

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I have huge javascript application which uses uncompiled requirejs. I want to make every request made on `js` file being serve with `mod_pagespeed`

How to configure it and make every js files requested minified. Thank you

I'm using apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box `mod_pagespeed` will optimize all javascript files referenced in the html, but with `requirejs` most scripts are going to be pulled in dynamically.  To optimize those files, turn on [`InPlaceResourceOptimization`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#ipro) (IPRO).  IPRO is also enabled by default in versions 1.9 and newer.

You might also want to check out [the optimization docs for `requirejs`](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

Comment: I'm sorry this work perfectly. Will look into optimization for requirejs to minimize request.